# How can I copy from excel table to Lucidchart entity relationship?

Tags: excel, copy, paste, lucidchart

I have a large number of rows in excel which I would like to use ase fields in an entity relationship in a Lucidchart ERD. When I try to copy this into Lucidchart it is pasted as a table and I can't convert it into a entity relationship. Is it possible to do this in any way?

Comment: There is no direct way to convert a spreadsheet to an ER diagram because a spreadsheet has no structured information about your db schema. You may get help here if you provide more information about how your spreadsheet file is structure and provide an example. Otherwise this question will be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

[This video from Lucidchart explains entity relationship diagrams (ERD) imports.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFjeJnV42Lg)

This video also covers how to access preformatted queries for your DBMS in order to obtain your .csv, .tsv etc.

- It sounds like you already have this in your excel file mentioned, but if not it is your query that builds the foundation for the db schema structure.
- Without that, Lucidchart won't know how to structure your data and will be a cause of the failed entity relationship mapping you're seeing.